# Cypress plugin crashed after add custom command

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress, nrwl-nx

I have Angular project with generated structure by [Nx](https://nx.dev/). I have configured Cypress and it worked fine till I want to add custom command `cy.el()`

This is my **commands.ts** file:

```js
import './commands.d';

Cypress.Commands.add('el', (id) => {
  return cy.get(`[test-id=${id}]`);
});
```

and **commands.d.ts** file:

```js
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    el(id: string): Chainable;
  }
}
```

When I try to run some of my test I got error:

> Error running plugin
>
> The following error was thrown by a plugin. We stopped running your
> tests because a plugin crashed. Please check your plugins file
> (\my-project\apps\my-app-e2e\src\plugins\index.js)
>
> TypeError: err.replace is not a function

Comment: Have you put your command.ts to support- or plugins-folder?

Comment: @MichaelK. files structure is generated by Nx, and commands.ts file is inside /support folder